# Apps Script new issues with V8 Runtime and JDBC

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

I've been coding and dealing with the typical V8 runtime issues for years now and managed to work arround them. However today even the simplest code is failing like this one:

```
function myFunction() {
 var j = Jdbc 
}
```

Is giving the error

> ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined myFunction    @ Code.gs:2

Yes, turning off V8 runtime fixes it, however it wasn't this broken yesterday! Yesterday (July 4 2022) this worked FINE.
Turning off V8 runtime in the project is not an option, there are other incompatible codes with previous runtime.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I  must admit I've never called it by itself but it continues to work for me coupled with getConnection().

Comment: Are you using a library?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194), when using libraries, while passing `jdbc` objects around or when mixing runtimes(v8+rhino engines). You may add `+1` on the top header of the issue.